# Combinatorics Question : Find Number of ways

Tags: combinatorics

You are given $3$ boxes of diamonds each containing $a$, $b$, $c$ number of diamonds you are given a chance to pick as much diamonds as possible but there are rules that you have to follow:
   - you have to pick two diamonds at a time
   - both of the diamonds must be from two different boxes
   - you can't place a picked diamond back into any of the boxes
There are different ways to pick the diamonds. Your aim is to pick as many diamonds as possible.

Find the number of ways you can do this.

Eg:

$a = 2,b=2, c=4$ gives $8$ ways
we can pick $2$ from $A$ and $2$ from $C$ . Now we can pick $2$ from $B$ and $2$ from $C$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Try using mathjax to make your questions more presentable!

Comment: Can you clarify what the $8$ ways are?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume WLOG that $a \le b \le c$. There are three cases that need to be examined separately: $a + b \le c$, $a + b > c$ with $a + b + c$ even, and $a + b > c$ with $a + b + c$ odd.

- If $a + b \le c$, then the maximum number of diamonds you can get is $2(a+b)$. You need to pick a diamond from $c$ every time.
- If $a + b > c$ and $a + b + c$ is even, then you can get all $a + b + c$ diamonds. In this case, you will need to pick from $a$ and $b$ a total of $\frac{a+b -c}2$ times. The remaining times you will pick one of the diamonds from $c$.
- If $a + b > c$ and $a + b + c$ is odd, then you can get $a + b + c -1$ diamonds. In this case you can either pick from $a$ and $b$ a total of $\left\lfloor\frac{a+b -c}2\right\rfloor$ times or $\left\lceil\frac{a+b -c}2\right\rceil$ times, and always pick a diamond from $c$ the remaining times.

So to determine the number of ways to do this, you will need count the number of ways to match the indicated number of diamonds from $a$ with those from $b$, then multiply that by the number of ways to match the remaining $c$ (or $c\pm 1$) diamonds in $a$ and $b$ combined with the diamonds in $c$.